# Difference between parallel and orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection

i would like to understand  what is a difference between parallel and  orthogonal projection?let us consider  following picture
[image]

We have two non othogonal basis and  vector  A with coordinates($7$,$2$),i would like to  find  parallel projection of this  vector to these basis,i am studying Covariant and Contrivant components,so i would like to understand how to find  parallel projection and also orthogonal projection?according to wikipedia, orthogonal projection is defined by

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection

what about parallel  projection?please help me

Comment: This page explains some of it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra).

Comment: but because  this  explanation is written in difficult language(i mean explanation is very  difficult)  that's  why i have posted question there.btw thanks for link

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the definition of *parallel projection*, and a quick internet search did not help. Can you tell me the definition you're using?

Comment: Do you mean vector rejection by parallel projection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In geometric terms ...

In a parallel projection, points are projected (onto some plane) in a direction that is parallel to some fixed given vector.

In an orthogonal projection, points are projected (onto some plane) in a direction that is normal to the plane.

So, all orthogonal projections are parallel projections, but not vice versa. A parallel projection that is not an orthogonal projection is called an "oblique" projection.

This could all be translated into the language of linear algebra, I suppose, but I don't think that would make it any clearer.

Comment: Here *plane* means a linear subspace of codimension 1?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. I'm thinking in terms of 3D geometry. I assumed that things like codimensions wouldn't help the OP much.

Comment: could you help me please how to find covariant and contravariant components of this vector?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with those concepts. Maybe someone else can try.

Comment: i will post it as    a new question

Comment: @bubba thanks for your answer here.  You seem to be implying that orthogonal projections consist of points that are both 1) normal to some plane and 2) parallel to some vector.  Let's say I have a matrix, $A$ whose column vectors describe a subspace, and I'm projecting the vector $v$ onto that subspace.  The formula for that is $A^T(A^TA)^{-1}Av$.  How does this formula translate to an orthogonal and or parallel projection?  Thanks again.