# Why is oblique projection not a self adjoint operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

Why is oblique projection not a self adjoint operator? [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515524/difference-between-parallel-and-orthogonal-projection) is an explanation of oblique projection.

Comment: It may be easier to prove the contrapositive: Every self-adjoint projection is an orthogonal projection.  The proof is very easy and would be a good exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is:

we want  $\ \forall x,y \ <Px,y> = <x,Py> $

If $P$ is orthogonal projection, then this is due to 
$$<Px,y>\  =\ <Px,Py>\ = \ <x,Py> $$
and the latter is due to the decomposition
$ y = Py + y^*$, so that for every $z$, $<y^*, Pz> = 0$. (That is, $y^*$ is orthogonal to the hyperplane we're projecting to.)  Therefore, $<Px,y>\  =\ <Px,Py>$.

But if your projection is not orthogonal, then $<y^*, Px> \ne 0$ and the above calculation fails.

(Try to picture it in 2 dimensions.)