# Confusion on terminology: "vector rejection", "vector projection", and "orthogonal projection"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices, projection

I have not found a satisfying answer to what is the difference between these three, intuitively:

1) vector projection

2) vector rejection

3) orthogonal projection

I know that "vector rejection of a onto b" will give me the vector that is orthogonal to the "vector projection of a onto b".  So, it would make sense to me that "vector rejection"  is synonymous with "orthogonal projection".  right?

But according to other sources, (e.g. ([difference between parallel and orthogonal projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515524/difference-between-parallel-and-orthogonal-projection/515540#comment5125811_515540)[here]))) "orthogonal projection" is somehow included in the definition of vector projection.

If that is the case, then I do not understand what is a projection that is *not* an orthogonal projection?

In your answer, feel free to show math - I can understand math.  But I'm having difficulty connecting the math to the definitions I see here on Stack Exchange.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The general case of projections is this:

Suppose a vector space $V$ decomposes as a direct sum of subspaces $U$ and $W$, i.e., $V = U \oplus W$. Then every $v \in V$ can be expressed uniquely as $v = u + w$, where $u \in U$ and $w \in W$.  We say that the vector $u$ is the *projection* of the vector $v$ onto the subspace $U$ (with respect to the decomposition $U \oplus W$).

Notice that this definition has nothing to do with orthogonality! We can project onto any subspace with respect to any decomposition.

Now let's look at orthogonal projections.  Assume, as above, $V = U \oplus W$, but now additionally we assume that $U$ and $W$ are orthogonal. (Here I must assume that $V$ is now an inner product space, so we have a notion of orthogonality. If you are not familiar with such spaces, you can just think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual notion of orthogonality.)

We designate one of the subspaces (say $U$) as the "parallel" one we are projecting onto, and the other one ($W$) as the "orthogonal" one. (I am using the terminology of the question you linked to.) Then, in your examples 1-3 above:

1. Vector projection is projection onto $U$.
2. Vector rejection is projection onto $W$.
3. Orthogonal projection is projection onto $W$ (same as 2).

Comment: What you are saying **almost** makes sense.  But if I look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) I see that "*orthogonal projection*" is used in _The vector projection of a vector onto a nonzero vector b is the orthogonal projection of a onto a straight line parallel to b_.  And, it is also used in the definition of *vector rejection*:  _The vector component or vector resolute of a perpendicular to b, also called the vector rejection of a from b,[1] is the orthogonal projection of a onto the plane orthogonal to b._  So it seems to me like 3.) is same as 1.) in our list above.

Comment: The terminology may not be totally standard. "Orthogonal projection" could mean "projection onto the orthogonal subspace" (which is 2 above) or  "projection in the orthogonal direction" (which is 1 above). Always check the definitions in the sources you are using.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small catch in wikipedia's definition of [vector rejection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) which i'm pointing out here:

The vector component or vector resolute of a **perpendicular** to b, sometimes also called the vector rejection of a **from** b, is the orthogonal projection of a onto the plane (or, in general, hyperplane) **orthogonal** to b.

Refer the diagram below:

[orthogonal projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0XG0.jpg)

This explains how orthogonal projection makes sense in both Vector Projection as well as Vector Rejection.