# Simple definition of vector rejection: $\vec p + \vec r = \vec v$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, definition, projection

Wikipedia defines [vector rejection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection#Vector_rejection) in a roundabout way.  This [math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483214/confusion-on-terminology-vector-rejection-vector-projection-and-orthogon) fills in the rigor.  But I'd like to confirm what to me is a very simple definition of *vector rejection*:

Let $\vec p$ be the vector projection of $\vec v$ onto $\vec w$.  Then the *vector rejection* $\vec r$ of $\vec v$ onto $\vec w$ is the unique vector such that $\vec p + \vec r = \vec v$.  Is that correct?

*Note:* A simple "Yes" will suffice as an acceptable answer (or comment); a proof of equivalence to a definition found elsewhere would be even better.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're decomposing the vector $\vec{v}$ with respect to an orthogonal frame defined by the direction of $\vec{w}$ (component $\vec{p}$ parallel to $\vec{w}$ and component $\vec{r}$ orthogonal to $\vec{w}$).

You can drag the head of the vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ around and see the resulting orthogonal projection $\vec{p}$ and rejection $\vec{r}$ vectors in [this interactive graphic](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jqmlexfzng).

[image: Orthogonal projection and rejection.]